# Different results when running commands in braces within a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curly-braces

I was editing a script and as the script was getting a bit long I decided to enclose the main part of the script in braces and divert the output to a log file instead of having individual log redirects for commands. Then I noticed that a command block that checks for a running copy of the script gives 2 different results depending if it is enclosed in braces.

I run the script as:

`$ /bin/bash scriptname.bash`

My question is why the same command block returns 2 different results and if it is possible to have the command block work inside the braces.

Below is the command block:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x   # Uncomment to debug this shell script
#
##########################################################
#         DEFINE FILES AND VARIABLES HERE
##########################################################
THIS_SCRIPT=$(basename $0)
TIMESTAMP=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S)
LOGFILE=process_check_$TIMESTAMP.log

##########################################################
#               BEGINNING OF MAIN
##########################################################

{
printf "%s\n" "Checking for currently runnning versions of this script"

MYPID=$$ # Capture this scripts PID
MYOTHERPROCESSES=$(ps -ef | \grep $THIS_SCRIPT | \grep -v $MYPID | \grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')

if [[ "$MYOTHERPROCESSES" != "" ]]
  then
    printf "%s\n" "ERROR: Another version of this script is running...exiting!"
    exit 2
  else
    printf "%s\n" "No other versions running...proceeding"
fi

printf "%s\n" "Doing some script stuff..."
exit 0

} | tee -a $LOGFILE 2>&1
# End of script
```

Comment: What is different in your output? Can you show the results or maybe a diff please.

Comment: Side note: if you want to log both standard output _and_ error, the redirection of stderr has to happen _before_ the pipe (or use `|&` for the pipe).

Comment: @Klaus - while in braces the block shows there is another script running. When outside the braces the block correctly evaluates that there is no other copy running.

Comment: @BenjaminW. - thanks for that. In my full script I assign error codes to various blocks and then trap those and execute different actions based on the error. I didn't include it here as I thought it not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not due to the braces, this is due to the pipe.

When you combine commands with a pipe like `command | tee`, each side of the pipe is executed in a separate sub-process. Shell commands are therefore executed in a sub-shell. That's this sub-shell that you detect.

PS: avoid constructs like `ps | grep -v grep`, use `pidof` or `pgrep` instead

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I guessed there were sub-shell shenanigans as the PIDS differed by the number of pipped commands. To me your suggestion of using `pidof` and `pgrep` is acceptable.

In addition I think it is sane enough to just move the 2 variables `MYPID` and `MYOTHERPROCESSES` outside the curly braces and bunch them with the rest of the variables.

Comment: @martin Your code inside curly braces is executed in a sub-shell. Whatever change you make to your variables there won't be visible outside the braces. To execute the code inside braces in the current shell, change `| tee -a $LOGFILE 2>&1` to `> >(tee -a $LOGFILE) 2>&1` (btw, the `2>&1` should have been placed before the pipe in your code)

Comment: on the `2>&1` bit you are spot on - this is how my original script is my mistake in the above submission. The remainder of my script inside curly braces does nothing more than testing different conditions with previously declared variables. As such I am happy the tests to be in a separate shell. However I will retest each block separately in and out of braces to make sure I get the expected result.

Thanks for you time and help on this.